# Not empty list of data from backing bean is empty in jsf form

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a form, that has a p:commandButton inside; when clicked on it, a function from managed bean is being invoked, which collects data into a list. I need to print this list in dialog in another form on the same jsf page. The problem is that, even though my list in backing bean is not empty, it is null when in form on jsf page. What am I doing wrong? These are the forms:

```
<h:form>
    <p:fieldset legend="Search for people" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" style="width: 365px">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" >
            <p:outputLabel for="confName" value="Name"/>
            <p:inputText id="confName" value="#{controler.name}" />
                   ...
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton update="gstSrch" id="searchButton" value="Search" actionListener="#{controler.search}"  />
    </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <p:repeat value="#{controler.people}" var="con" id="gstSrch" rendered="#{not empty controler.people}">
        <p:panelGrid columns="4">
            <h:outputText value="#{con.name}"/>
                   ....
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:repeat>
</h:form>
```

Managed bean is SessionScoped, and it works wll when used in all other forms. 
Would you be so kind and point me in the right direction? It seems like it either resets somehow, or is never actually set. I tried to put Application Scoped to my managed bean, but the result is same.  I also putt all of this in one form, still the result is same.
Thank you.

Comment: put it in one form and change button attribute like `update="@form"`

Comment: @Vasil Lukach Thank you, that solved it!

Comment: Not using one form was most likely not the real issue. Having a wrong value in the update attribute most likely was, but your problem description was not that good... The other answer was just as good... So please learn how to use/what to put in an update attribute. Learn about namingcontainers which prepend their id to child elements and learn how to addres elements in other namingcontainers... Valuable knowledge!!!

Answer (score 2):

Assign an id to your second form an use it to update your component

```
<h:form>
    <p:fieldset legend="Search for people" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" style="width: 365px">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" >
            <p:outputLabel for="confName" value="Name"/>
            <p:inputText id="confName" value="#{controler.name}" />
                   ...
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton update=":myForm:gstSrch" id="searchButton" value="Search" actionListener="#{controler.search}"  />
    </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:repeat value="#{controler.people}" var="con" id="gstSrch" rendered="#{not empty controler.people}">
        <p:panelGrid columns="4">
            <h:outputText value="#{con.name}"/>
                   ....
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:repeat>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Please add a little more explanation to this answer, since it is also a valid one but lacks explanation as to why this works (the other answer/comment lacks this to btw)

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150063/5527433) is a good explanation on how to use ids to update elements.

Answer (score 0):

So, as @Vasil Lukach said, this did a job for me:

```
<h:form>
  <p:fieldset legend="Search for people" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" style="width: 365px">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" >
        <p:outputLabel for="confName" value="Name"/>
        <p:inputText id="confName" value="#{controler.name}" />
               ...
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton update="@form" id="searchButton" value="Search" actionListener="#{controler.search}"  />
  </p:fieldset>

  <p:repeat value="#{controler.people}" var="con" id="gstSrch" rendered="#{not empty controler.people}">
    <p:panelGrid columns="4">
        <h:outputText value="#{con.name}"/>
               ....
    </p:panelGrid>
  </p:repeat>
</h:form>
```